# Accessing USB camera controls with AForge

Tags: c#, directshow.net, aforge

I have a project where i need to work with a USB camera to process images aquired at a very close range (under 5mm). Because the space available is very short, I can't use auxiliary lens.

I know I can do some post processing at bitmap level, but I would like to gain access to properties like auto-focus or white balancing at camera level.

I'm developing in C# with AForge for image aquisition and post processing, but I can't seem to find a way to control the camera before the image aquisition takes place.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some more thorough research I've found the [answer](http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1969) by myself.

If anyone else is searching for this you can try the following;

```
VideoCaptureDevice Cam1;
FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;

VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
Cam1 = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
Cam1.DisplayPropertyPage(IntPtr.Zero); //This will display a form with camera controls
```

It also seems possible to control these items without the form by using IAMVideoProcAmp

Comment: @Darshana The edit you made was too minor. That should not have been approved, so I rolled it back. Please put more effort into your edits. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) if you are not sure how to properly edit posts.

Answer (score 7):

You can access camera setting directly without call the method DisplayPropertyPage()

```
FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = 
    new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

VideoCaptureDevice videoDevice = 
    new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[camDevice].MonikerString);

videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
    CameraControlProperty.Zoom,
    zoomValue,
    CameraControlFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
    CameraControlProperty.Focus,
    focusValue,
    CameraControlFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetCameraProperty(
    CameraControlProperty.Exposure,
    exposureValue,
    CameraControlFlags.Manual);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access other camera properties like brightness, contrast see
[IAMVideoProcAmp implementation](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/issues/detail?id=357#makechanges)

```
videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.Brightness,
    brightnessValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.Contrast,
    contrastValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.Saturation,
    saturationValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.Sharpness,
    sharpnessValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.WhiteBalance,
    whiteBalanceValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);

videoDevice.SetVideoProperty(
    VideoProcAmpProperty.BacklightCompensation,
    backlightCompensationValue,
    VideoProcAmpFlags.Manual);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You have added valuable information to my initial idea: that it was possible to set these using the IAMVideoProcAmp. It's a couple of years since my first post, but the information may still be relevant to some users.

Comment: The code.google.com reference no longer exists. Luckily this github project cloned Aforge and brought the changes in: https://github.com/lanpa/AForge.NET